# a bug in python private-attribute_class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below code

```
class AccountBannk:
    def __init__(self,balance,holder):
        self.__AccountHolder=holder
    def Display_AccountHolder(self):
        print "account holder is" , self.__AccountHolder
myaccount=AccountBannk(100000,"mehdiebagvand")
#print myaccount.__AccountHolder #is a error
myaccount.__AccountHolder="ali"
print myaccount.__AccountHolder      #print ali
```

in this code AccountHolder is a private attribute
and in python we can not directly edit or print it.
if we try below code, python release a error

```
print myaccount.__AccountHolder
```

but my questions are
1-why python not release error in below code

```
myaccount.__AccountHolder="ali"
```

2-I print myaccount.__AccountHolder in end_line but python not release error
and change the value of myaccount.__AccountHolder to 'ali'

Comment: Change it to `ali` and then call `Display_AccountHolder()`.

Comment: Display_AccountHolder() work good but my qestion is another

Comment: Well, what does `Display_AccountHolder()` print out?

Comment: print account holder ismehdiebagvand

Comment: Exactly. You created a new attribute with the value of `ali`, but left the "private" one intact.

Comment: ok tankyou thus is not a bug    ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug.  When you are defining your first `__AccountHolder` inside you class, Python is mangling the variable's name (making it hard to guess, but not truly private, see [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).  When you attach your second `__AccountHolder` you are creating a new varible (with a new mangled name).  Try this to see:

```
print myaccount.__AccountHolder
print myaccount.Display_AccountHolder()
```

Or add

```
print dir(myaccount)
```

Before and after you do that second assignment like so:

```
>>> myaccount=AccountBannk(100000,"mehdiebagvand")
>>> dir(myaccount)
    ['Display_AccountHolder', '_AccountBannk__AccountHolder', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
>>> myaccount.__AccountHolder="ali"
>>> dir(myaccount)
    ['Display_AccountHolder', '_AccountBannk__AccountHolder', '__AccountHolder', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
```

And as for the name mangling, here it is from the documentation:

> __double_leading_underscore: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, __boo becomes *FooBar*_boo; see
>   below).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons I believe that it's *way* more trouble than it's worth to use `__names` as "private variables". The intended use case of `__names` is more to allow classes in a hierarchy to use nice(ish) names without worrying so much about what names are in use by other classes in the hierarchy, not to create "private" attributes.

For "private" attributes, just use single leading underscores (like `_name`). This documents your intention that certain names are private implementation details, while others are part of the class' public interface. It doesn't *prevent* anyone using the "private" name, but neither do `__names` because the mangling is very easy to reverse-engineer. All either of these techniques do is prevent anyone from *accidentally* using a name you intended to be private; they can do dodgy things, but they have to know that they're doing it. This is all you can ever get in Python; because everything is dynamic anyone can do anything at any time anyway.

So the major difference between `__name` and `_name` for your private internal names is that `__name` will become a major PITA whenever you start wanting to use `getattr` or `hasattr` (even within the correct class), dynamically attach methods, or have a subclass that *does* want to share the "private" name. A `_name` with a single underscore has no problems in any of those areas, is just as effective at documenting your intention, and is just as effective (i.e. almost completely ineffective) in preventing private names being used outside the class definition.